# dimple graph , 2 variables from a tsv file, what am i doing wrong ?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

Wanted to make a simple graph with dimple as a beginner.
I wanted to use the following example from the dimple page:

http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=lines_horizontal

```
<html>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script src="/lib/d3.v3.4.8.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.tsv("/data/example_data.tsv", function (data) {
      data = dimple.filterData(data, "Owner", ["Aperture", "Black Mesa"])
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
      var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month");
      x.addOrderRule("Date");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Unit Sales");
      var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
</html>
```

i know i have to change the filename of the .tsv file and it contains in my case the colums year and attendance. 
I think i am making a mistake in the filterData line,

can someone spot my mistake and how i can get it going ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script src="/lib/d3.v3.4.8.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.tsv("world_cup.tsv", function (data) {
      data = dimple.filterData(data, "year","attendance")
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
      var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Attendance");
      x.addOrderRule("Date");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Year");
      var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry that i dont understand the comment, could you maybe provide me with some additonal information ? It comes traight from the dimple example page :(

Comment: haven't used dimple but filterData third parameter looks odd to me... is attendance a possible value for year?

Comment: No, attendance and year a both columns in the tsv file. So my graph should have year on one axis and attendance on the other

Comment: @hmmmbob then you are not properly using the API, see the docs: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple#filterData

Comment: i tried this : data = dimple.filterData(data, ["year","attendance"]) gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined :(

Comment: `dataFilter` is just used to filter your dataset by some field... if that's not necessary, `addCategoryAxis` and `addMeasureAxis` are already selecting the necessary variables in your plot. Try to drop the filter line, and modify the following lines as follows: `var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "attendance");` (assuming "attendance" is a valid field name in your dataset) and `myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "year");` (assuming year is a valid field name in your dataset)

Comment: Thank you so much !! . you are a lifesaver... :)

Comment: should I move this into an answer?